# Using static variables in operations

Tags: java, static

I am trying to make this simple game of Odds and Evens. The program works flawlessly until "1". The problem is: instead of multiplying "finger" and "computer", it directly gives the value of "computer" and while I do not get any errors from rest of the code I do not get any output either. I made "name", "oe" and "finger" static to be able to use them outside the loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class OddsAndEvens {
static String name; 
static String oe;
static int finger;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Let’s play a game called “Odds and Evens”");
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String name = input.next();
    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Hello " + name + " which one do you choose? (O)dds or (E)vens?");
        String oe = input.next();

        if (oe.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
            System.out.println(name + " has picked evens! The computer will be odds.");
            break;
        }
        if (oe.equalsIgnoreCase("o")) {
            System.out.println(name + " has picked odds! The computer will be evens.");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have typed an invalid answer, lets try again");
        }
    }

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("How many \"fingers\" do you put out? ");
        int finger = input.nextInt();
        if (finger >= 0 && finger <= 5) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please write a number between 0 and 5");
        }
    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    int computer = rand.nextInt(5) + 0;
    System.out.println("Computer plays number " + computer);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");

    int sum = finger + computer; //1<------------------------------
    if (sum % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(sum + " is even!");
        if (oe.equalsIgnoreCase("e") && (sum % 2 == 0)) {
            System.out.println(name + " wins!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Computer wins!");
        }

        if (sum % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println(sum + " is odd!");
            if (oe.equalsIgnoreCase("o") && (sum % 2 != 0)) {
                System.out.println(name + " wins!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Computer wins!");
            }


        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: @E.Canberk When you do `int finger = input.nextInt();`, you are shadowing your static `finger` variable. A simple fix would be to do `finger = input.nextInt();`, which will instead assign a value to the static variable (ignoring the fact that static variables are bad). The same thing happens with your `name` and `oe` variables.

Comment: How can `if (sum % 2 != 0) ` ever be true when it is inside the block of `if (sum % 2 == 0) { }`?

Comment: Don't declare them as static. Just declare them (non-static) before you enter the loops, and do not re-declare them inside the loops.

Comment: @marstran What do you mean by "Static Variables are bad"? Can you express it? And if so which another method can be used instead of static in order to use a variable outside a loop or void ?

Comment: @E.Canberk A static variable is defined on the class (not an object of the class). This means that all objects of the class will see the same value. This can lead to a whole heap of problems, especially in the context of multi-threading. It's basically Java's version of a "global variable". If you want to use a variable outside a loop, then just define it outside the loop. Preferably inside the same method as the loop, but you can also define is a _non-static_ variable on the class.

Comment: @marstran For example, in the code above variable 'oe' is defined as Scanner input and therefore it needs to be in that particular place. How can I define a variable without giving a value ? For example, shall I just write String oe = ""; to beginning and use oe = "a"; to give it a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you have is that you are declaring your variables "name", "oe" and "finger" twice. Instead of `int finger = input.nextInt();` you should just write `finger = input.nextInt();` because with your code you are declaring a new variable calles finger inside the loop and using it just inside the loop, when your program steps outside the loop it is going to use the static variable finger witch will be equals to zero and that's why you are always getting the value of computer.

you're not getting any output for the same reason, the "oe" you're updating is not the same as the one you are testing in your if statements

and you're if statements are also mixed up, the second if statement is inside the first.

you're new code should be :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Let’s play a game called “Odds and Evens”");
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    name = input.next();
    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Hello " + name + " which one do you choose? (O)dds or (E)vens?");
        oe = input.next();

        if (oe.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
            System.out.println(name + " has picked evens! The computer will be odds.");
            break;
        }
        if (oe.equalsIgnoreCase("o")) {
            System.out.println(name + " has picked odds! The computer will be evens.");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have typed an invalid answer, lets try again");
        }
    }

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("How many \"fingers\" do you put out? ");
        finger = input.nextInt();
        if (finger >= 0 && finger <= 5) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please write a number between 0 and 5");
        }
    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    int computer = rand.nextInt(5) + 0;
    System.out.println("Computer plays number " + computer);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");

    int sum = finger + computer; //1<------------------------------
    if (sum % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(sum + " is even!");
        if (oe.equalsIgnoreCase("e") && (sum % 2 == 0)) {
            System.out.println(name + " wins!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Computer wins!");
        }
    }

    else {
        System.out.println(sum + " is odd!");
        if (oe.equalsIgnoreCase("o") && (sum % 2 != 0)) {
            System.out.println(name + " wins!");
        } else {
                System.out.println("Computer wins!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second while loop, you initialise a new local variable `finger` that is valid only inside the while loop by saying `int finger =` instead of calling the global static variable finger by saying `finger =`.

In the result, the global variable `finger` has not been initialised and `sum` has nothing to add to the variable `computer`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using static values in class you shouldn't initialize them second time inside while instructions, where they are local ones - so once you're writing to local ones and ones you are using class variables. 
Second thing is dividing your if. If checking if sum is odd should be another part that one checking if it's even. It can also be made by if...else .
Your code:

```
package stackoverflow;
```

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class OddsAndEvens {

```
static String name; 
static String oe;
static int finger;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Let’s play a game called “Odds and Evens”");
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    name = input.next();
    while (true) {

        System.out.println("Hello " + name + " which one do you choose? (O)dds or (E)vens?");
        oe = input.next();

        if (oe.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
            System.out.println(name + " has picked evens! The computer will be odds.");
            break;
        }
        if (oe.equalsIgnoreCase("o")) {
            System.out.println(name + " has picked odds! The computer will be evens.");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have typed an invalid answer, lets try again");
        }
    }

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("How many \"fingers\" do you put out? ");
        finger = input.nextInt();
        if (finger >= 0 && finger <= 5) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please write a number between 0 and 5");
        }
    }

    Random rand = new Random();
    int computer = rand.nextInt(5) + 0;
    System.out.println("Computer plays number " + computer);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");

    int sum = finger + computer; //1<------------------------------
    if (sum % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println(sum + " is even!");
        if (oe.equalsIgnoreCase("e") && (sum % 2 == 0)) {
            System.out.println(name + " wins!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Computer wins!");
        }
    }
    if (sum % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println(sum + " is odd!");
            if (oe.equalsIgnoreCase("o") && (sum % 2 != 0)) {
                System.out.println(name + " wins!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Computer wins!");
            }


    }

}
```